# Implement rpm task in gradle

Tags: ant, gradle, build.gradle, rpmbuild

I am trying to migrate from ant to gradle to build my rpm-package. I found one plugin `gradle-ospackage-plugin`, but I am not able to understand how to use any of commands which I have in ant task: `specFile, topDir, command, cleanbuildDir, failonError`

Is it not possible to have them in gradle?

Update: Basically I am trying to replicate the following in gradle

```
<target name="myrpm">
    <rpm specFile = "topdir"
         topDir = "topdir" />
</target>
```

I was also looking into running ant tasks from gradle such as `ant.echo(message: "hello)`.
But `ant.rpm` is not resolving.

Comment: The question ins unclear. What's the problem exactly? Where are the mentioned commands defined? What's wrong with plugin?

Comment: You can *either* use the `ant.rpm` task, *or* a Gradle plugin such as `gradle-ospackage-plugin`. As a general guideline, if a Gradle plugin exists I'd first try that. From what I remember, the `gradle-ospackage-plugin` is documented quite well on its Github page.

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser. I am trying `ant.rpm`. But it not working. I keep getting Could not find property 'rpm'. Do I need to import anything in the classpath?

Comment: Third-party Ant tasks need to be imported (see [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html) for details).

Comment: I don't think `rpm` is a third-party ant task. I did not have to import anything in ant classpath to use ant for the build.

Comment: I don't think that `ant.rpm` will work as-is. You'll have to use `ant.rpm(some: "arg", another: "arg")`, or at the very least `ant.rpm()`.

Comment: Note that "[ant.rpm] currently only works on Linux or other Unix platforms with rpm support.", while gradle-ospackage-plugin works well cross-platform since it's 100% Java/Gradle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple example that creates two RPMs. If you want a single RPM then use one task. Your build.gradle file should be like this.

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id "nebula.ospackage" version "3.2.0"
}


task one(type: Rpm) {
    packageName = 'one-pack'
    version = '1.0.0'
    release = '1'
    arch = I386
    os = LINUX

    from('./src/main/resources') {
        into 'apps/lib/'
    }
}

task two(type: Rpm) {
    packageName = 'two-pack'
    version = '2.2.0'
    release = '2'
    arch = I386
    os = LINUX
}

apply plugin: 'nebula.ospackage'

group 'com.avishek'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    compile 'org.assertj:assertj-core:3.2.0'
}
```

Run the project with the following command:

```
  ./gradlew clean two one
```

Comment: Nice example works with a copy/paste first try!